# Is it better to use "deliver" or "deliver in"?

Tags: grammar

> This machine sorts letters into "delivery point sequence," or the
>   order that postal carriers will deliver them along their routes.

Is it better to say:

(1) This machine sorts letters into "delivery point sequence," or the order that postal carriers will deliver them along their routes.
or
(2) This machine sorts letters into "delivery point sequence," the order that postal carriers will deliver them in along their routes.

The preposition "in" seems necessary to me, and I'm very interested in reading any responses here to my question.  (The sample sentence is from a USPS TV YouTube video.)

Comment: *The delivery order used by postal carriers.* Also, it should be ***a*** *delivery point sequence* or *delivery points* ***sequences***.

Comment: @JasonBassford, while I think the ending of the sentence works as you've stated, I think by removing the quotes and making it "a delivery point sequence" you would change the meaning of the sentence since "delivery point sequence" seems to be a specific term which is being defined.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, I believe the grammatically correct way would be:

> This machine sorts letters into "delivery point sequence," the order **in which** postal carriers will deliver them along their routes.

That said, I believe this is becoming somewhat archaic. To Jason's point in the comments you could also rewrite the second part of the sentence altogether to eliminate the need for 'in':

> This machine sorts letters into "delivery point sequence," the delivery order postal carriers use on their routes.

Comment: ". . . the delivery order used by postal carriers" is succinct and clear, isn't it? (I almost missed Jason Bradfor's response -- for the smaller font (typeface).)

Comment: I think this will get into a slight subtlety about the intent of the sentence and who the audience is. That said, I agree "the delivery order used by postal carriers [on their routes]" is more clear.